# apk add for alpine Docker image loads old version of yarn (1.16)

Tags: docker, yarnpkg, alpine-linux

I am creating a container based on the ruby:2.6-alpine image and trying to add yarn. When I check the yarn version, I get 1.16 while I want something more recent (1.17 specifically.)

What do I have to do get the latest version of Yarn on an alpine image?

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM ruby:2.6-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add build-base nodejs postgresql-dev bash yarn curl git

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
CMD bash
```

Comment: The image is based on `alpine:3.10` which only provides 1.16. If you could find a ruby image based on `alpine:edge`, you could get 1.19. I don't see one on DockerHub...

Comment: Alternatively can I set the repository somehow and get the later version of yarn on the 3.10 image, per the description at https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management#Add_a_Package ? I used the URL that's on the wiki to add yarn, but that installed 1.16 too. Is there a different repo URL that might work?

Comment: Ok, I found it - the packages are in community rather than testing, so all I had to do was add an update from there for yarn. @hmm If you want to write that as an answer, I shall gladly mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your base image [ruby:2.6-alpine](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/5c9e21cbf79b7f36d505555c9ecd62cf0f7e07f8/2.6/alpine3.10/Dockerfile) is based on alpine v3.10 repository so that is why you get yarn `1.16`.
[image]

[alpine yarn branch v3.10](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=yarn&branch=v3.10&repo=community)

All you need to install it from this [repo](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=yarn&branch=edge&repo=community).

```
RUN apk add --no-cache yarn --repository="http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" 
RUN yarn -v
```

Comment: Although this may solve the problem now, it's not guaranteed to work next week. Over time edge will diverge more and more from 3.10 and eventually lead to incompatibilities in the depending libraries. A cleaner and more futureproff-way would be to change your code to work with yarn 1.16+. Or you request a backport of the current yarn version into 3.10 via a github / gitlab issue.